# endless loop while trying to triangulate the surface

Tags: vtk

I have an OBJ file that I wanna cover the holes. The steps that I did was:
 1. Use vtk filters to triangulate and fill holes
 2. Manually check for the holes and fill it follow this help http://vtk.1045678.n5.nabble.com/Filling-a-hole-td1225339.html but it got stuck in an endless loop

When I use slicer to open the shape generated from step 1 above, the slicer successfully filled the holes for me (please see the screenshot). I then went to slicer github (https://github.com/Slicer/Slicer/blob/f4a792d66b910edc54060566573d13264f3951fc/Modules/Scripted/SurfaceToolbox/SurfaceToolbox.py) and search for how slicer fill holes but i can't see the difference.

I have created 2 gist for the 2 steps that I did here: https://gist.github.com/ngunhaSO/494866ac6c19965c760c4ef1b46e7539
and https://gist.github.com/ngunhaSO/cfc3184854d0ca6bf57d3c4637fb6d13

The obj file is here: https://github.com/ngunhaSO/misc/blob/master/1_with_wall.obj

The screenshot when open the stl file from slicer: 
[image]

The screenshot from my wxpython

[image]

Does anyone have any suggestion?